# Why can I not print from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, printing

When I try to print any page from Chrome on my Windows 7 machine, I get the following message.

[[image: Printing from Chrome does not work.]<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADn87.png)

By the way, the gray text in the middle reads

> Google Chrome cannot show the print preview when the built-in PDF viewer is disabled. In order to see the preview please visit chrome//plugins/, enable the Chrome PDF Viewer, and try again.

When I check my plugins, I find that Chrome PDF Viewer is already enabled. Why can't I print?

Comment: Are you getting this problem on any webpage or just PDFs?

Comment: I am getting this problem on any web page I visit. I was trying to print google.com in this example.

Comment: Disabling the built-in PDF viewer isn't giving me any error messages when I try to print on WinXP. I'll test on Win7 this evening.  Also, I notice your screen print has an empty Destination drop-down box. What happens if you try to select your printer?

Comment: Thank you, when I try to select a printer, no options appear in the list. However, I do have my printer hooked up since I can print from Microsoft Word and Internet Explorer.

Comment: OK, I've tried it from home now also. Win7 64 bit with Chrome 16.0.912.75 m. Disabling the built-in PDF viewer doesn't cause me any problem with print preview. I think your problem is really the the missing printers. I don't have any suggestion for that other than to uninstall & reinstall Chrome. :-(

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. I did not have this problem until recently. My printers are alive and well. The plugin is enabled. I am not trying to print a PDF but a webpage. Chrome gives the error described above...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use `Print using system dialog` with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Try disabling the Adobe Reader plug in to solve the problem.

Comment: When I use the shortcut I cant select my printers in Windows 7, 64-bit. I can use the printers from Word, I can print testpages so it IS installed, but Chrome cant use them???